# Update CSV line with new data and save file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, csv

I have the following data which im reading from a CSV coma delimited file, it contains 8 columns:
***ID, Name, Subject, Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, Grade4, Grade5, Final***

Here's a sample of the data:

```
1,Allan Wilkinson,Calculo I,3.4,2.5,5,5,3.2
1,Allan Wilkinson,Calculo II,1,4.1,3.5,3.7,2.7
1,Allan Wilkinson,Fisica I,3,3.2,3.7,4.2,5
2,Rexanne Dickinson,Fisica II,4.3,3.4,2.5,5,3.5
2,Rexanne Dickinson,Estadistica,2.3,1,4.1,3.5,5
2,Rexanne Dickinson,Calculo I,3.4,2.5,5,3.7,3.5
3,Meaghan Neely,Calculo II,1,4.1,3.5,2.5,5
3,Meaghan Neely,Fisica I,3,3.2,3.7,4.1,3.5
3,Meaghan Neely,Fisica II,4.3,2.1,2.5,4.5,3.2
4,Ariana Donkin,Estadistica,1,4.1,4.3,2.1,2.5
4,Ariana Donkin,Calculo I,3,3.2,1,4.1,4.1
4,Ariana Donkin,Calculo II,3.4,3.2,1,4.1,3.2
5,Camron Jenner,Fisica I,2.1,2.5,5,2.5,2.5
5,Camron Jenner,Fisica II,4.1,4.1,3.5,4.1,4.3
```

I'm trying to write a Bash program in which the user is able to enter a new line or update a current one, and save the data into the CSV file.

The code I currently have reads and matches the requested data and also asks for the new data. I tried to implement awk but im not really sure how to do it, or if it can actually accomplish the job.

Here's the code:

```
echo "Enter the student ID";
read student;

while IFS=, read -r ID name subject grade1 grade2 grade3 grade4 grade5 finalg
do
if [[ $ID == $student ]]; then
echo "$subject $grade1 $grade2 $grade3 $grade4 $grade5 $finalg";
fi
done < grades.csv

echo "Enter Subject to Modify or Enter a New one to Add";
read modSubject;

echo "Enter Grade1";
read grade1new;

echo "Enter Grade2";
read grade2new;

echo "Enter Grade3";
read grade3new;

echo "Enter Grade4";
read grade4new;

echo "Enter Grade5";
read grade5new;

total=$(echo "$grade1new + $grade2new + $grade3new + $grade4new + $grade5new" | bc);
final=$(echo "scale=2; $total/5" | bc);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there :-)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the student ID";
read student;

while IFS=, read -r ID name subject grade1 grade2 grade3 grade4 grade5 finalg
do
    if [[ "$ID" = "$student" ]]; then
        echo "$subject $grade1 $grade2 $grade3 $grade4 $grade5 $finalg"
        snm="$name"  # <-we need the name so we store it here, safe 
    fi
done < grades.csv

echo "Enter Subject to Modify or Enter a New one to Add"; read modSubject;
echo "Enter Grade1"; read grade1new;
echo "Enter Grade2"; read grade2new;
echo "Enter Grade3"; read grade3new;
echo "Enter Grade4"; read grade4new;
echo "Enter Grade5"; read grade5new;

total=$(echo "$grade1new + $grade2new + $grade3new + $grade4new + $grade5new" | bc);
final=$(echo "scale=2; $total/5" | bc);

#drop the old record
grep -v "^$student,$snm,$modSubject," grades.csv >tmp$$

#add the new record
echo "$student,$snm,$modSubject,$grade1new,$grade2new,$grade3new,$grade4new,$grade5new,$final" >>tmp$$ 
mv tmp$$ grades.csv
```

Just two minor changes was all you need.
The first is a small change in the while loop because we need the name.
The last is deleting the old record (if it exists) and adding a new one.
The output is unsorted. If you want to have it sorted, just add `sort grades.csv -o grades.csv` at the end.

Sure it can be optimized a bit, but I didn't want to tinker too much with your code :-)